# php array acts as string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I call a php script from an ajax request and I'm supposed to get an array back containing multiple values but the javascript code sees it as a normal string. This is the response I get:

```
Message,ID
```

Can anyone help me with getting back a normal array? I tried multiple loops but it just gets me parts of the whole thing (if I, for example, do a foreach loop I get something like "M", "e", "s" etc)

Hope someone can help me because I'm stuck here. I tried returning the data as Json array and as a normal array.

PHP:

```
$result = $this->dataHandle->prepare("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE Receiver = ? AND ID > ? ORDER BY ID DESC ");
    $result->execute(array($_SESSION['ID'], $_SESSION['count']));
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['count'] = $row['ID'];
        $tmp;
        $tmp[] = $row['Message'];
        $tmp[] = $row['Password'];
        $temp[] = $tmp;
    }
    return $temp;
```

Javascript:

```
var z = result.toString();
var a = z.indexOf(",");
var message = z.substring(0, a);
```

Comment: can you post the js and php

Comment: Did you also decode it as JSON when you returned a JSON array?

Comment: as @atmd sad, show us the codes.

Comment: if the `response` is a string `"Message,ID"` then you can convert it to an array using `response.split(",")`. If it was encoded as JSON string `"['Message','ID']"` then `JSON.parse( response )` to convert to an array.

Comment: Php:
`$result = $this->dataHandle->prepare("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE Receiver = ? AND ID > ? ORDER BY ID DESC ");
     $result->execute(array($_SESSION['ID'], $_SESSION['count']));
      while ($row = $result->fetch())
      {
                $_SESSION['count'] = $row['ID'];
                $tmp;
                $tmp[] = $row['Message'];
                $tmp[] = $row['Password'];
                $temp[] = $tmp;
      }
return $temp;`

Javascript:
`
var z = result.toString();
                var a = z.indexOf(",");
                var message = z.substring(0, a);`

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting string as your ajax response you can use split function

`response.split(',')'

and you will get an array or you can use json to pass values through ajax to javascript.